# Why can't I refer to my @quiz variable in 'update' action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My QuizzesController#index action looks like this:

```
def index
    @user = current_user
    @quiz = Quiz.create(user_id: current_user.id)
end
```

My view draws the quiz form fine. It goes to the results/index view as intended. BUT the various attributes of the quiz are NOT updated on the Quiz instance which is pulled from the database, in the QuizzesContoller#update action:

```
def update
    @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id).last
    redirect_to results_path
end
```

('update' is called in this case because the Quiz instance already exists, having been created in the 'index' action).

So, I tried changing the 'update' action to:

```
def update
    @quiz.save
    @results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id).last
    redirect_to results_path
end
```

But this triggers the error:
`undefined method 'save' for nil:NilClass`

Why is that? Shouldn't my QuizzesController have access to the @quiz variable as set up in the 'index' action? Can anyone explain what the problem is there?

Comment: My Quiz object is created when a user goes to the quiz page. When they click 'submit' Rails says it wants to use the 'update' action. If what I'm doing is wrong, how WOULD I update the database with a user's quiz answers when they click 'submit'?

Comment: how many quizes allows per user?

Comment: Are you not sending the quiz's Id with the PUT/PATCH request?  If so, you can get the quiz via `@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])`.  Also, do not do a `create` in your `index`, it breaks standard CRUD and REST conventions.  `index` should only be used in a GET request to return a list of objects.  `create` should only be used in a POST request.  The way you have it set up, you are creating a quiz record before a form to save data to it is rendered.  What if the user closes the browser?  You will have rogue quiz records throughout your DB.

Comment: @Малъ Скрылевъ: User `has_one :quiz`. As for the other comment, I don't KNOW which http verb is being used. How am I supposed to know? Also I think I'm confusing the Model of the quiz with the actual displayed quiz. I think you're saying the Model should only be created when the quiz is completed and I need to store the answers. That makes a kind of sense. If I'm wrong about that, please let me know.

Comment: `@results = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id).last` -> `@results` is a quiz, so you have to just update the found quiz with data from `params` and I believe the proper redirect is: `redirect_to @results`

Comment: @tagCincy : If I don't make a quiz instance variable BEFORE the quiz, and send that to the view (to be passed to form_for), how does the form 'know' which object to refer to when the user clicks 'submit'?

Comment: @moosefetcher you don't need additional quiz becasue `@results` is the `@quiz`

Comment: I know I only need one quiz, but I'm asking about WHEN that should be created. Surely it needs to be created before the user views the quiz, so that the `form_for` has an object parameter?

Comment: @quiz should be created in `create` action, inside the `update` action it should be just found out (and updated)

Comment: OK, but then HOW does the form_for in my form know which object to use?

Comment: @moosefetcher just `form_for @quiz`

Comment: I think this has been answered on another question I asked: I don't think you're understanding what it is I DON'T understand. It didn't occur to me that I could pass a 'new' Quiz to the form - which would NOT save it to the database. The problem I'm having now is the Quiz that gets created in the 'create' action doesn't seem to get updated with a user's answers. But that's another question, I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others have answered this question, so I thought I would explain why the answer is what it is.  In Ruby, variables that begin with the @ symbol are instance variables.  This means that they are created when a new instance of their parent object is instantiated and are unique to that instance of the object.

Rails based web apps, for the most part, are stateless, meaning that state is not persisted between http requests.  In layman terms, the app treats each and every request independent of all other requests.  Due to this, the controllers are instanced classes.  Every request instantiates a new instance of the controller class.

EDIT:

More I look at your code, you aren't following proper conventions

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController

    # GET index: for displaying a list of quizzes
    def index
        @quizzes = Quiz.where(user_id: current_user.id)
    end

    # GET show:  for getting a single quiz record
    def show
        @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
    end

    # GET new: for initializing a new quiz record
    def new
        @quiz = Quiz.new
    end

    # POST create:  for saving a new quiz record
    def create
        @quiz = current_user.quizzes.create(quiz_params)

        if @quiz.errors
            render :new
        else
            redirect_to @quiz #or whereever
        end
    end

    # GET edit:  for initializing existing quiz for update
    def edit
        @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id)
    end

    # PUT/PATCH update:  for updating an existing quiz record
    def update
        @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])

        if @quiz.update(quiz_params)
            redirect_to @quiz # or whereever
        else
            render :edit
    end

    # DELETE destroy:  for deleting a quiz record
    def destroy
        Quiz.find(params[:id]).destroy
        redirect_to :index # or whereever
    end
end
```

Comment: OK, I come from an OOP background, so 1) I was thinking `Quiz.new` was making a new Model, and 2) I was expecting that instance to persist. But knowing a new Controller is being instantiated for each http request is very useful. Thank you for explaining that! Although, thinking some more about it, I'm still a bit woolly on WHY `Quiz.new` DOESN'T make a persistent Model object...

Comment: I THINK I've just figured it out some more - the Model persists but the Controller does not. Is that right?

Comment: `.new` instantiates a new Quiz object, `.create` persists the object by running `.save` on the object after instantiating it.  `.new` is actually inherit from the Ruby Object class, you can run it on any Ruby class.

Answer (score 0):

You have not `@quiz` variable in your update action. Actions in the controller does not have access to variables in other actions.

Answer (score 0):

The `QuizzesController` instance is not persisted between requests. The real reason instance variables are used in controllers is to pass that variable to the view.

A normal update action would look something like:

```
def update
  @quiz = current_user.quiz # I'm assuming a user has one quiz?
  @quiz.update(quiz_params) # Where quiz params takes the posted parameters from your update form
  if @quiz.errors.any?
    render :edit
  else
    redirect_to results_path
  end
```

The key is you need to reassign `@quiz` with each request

Comment: Even if the user has multiple quizzes, I would assume that he is sending the quiz_id with the PUT/PATCH request. Therefore, he can get the current quiz record with a simple `@quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])`